# React Admin Disable Pagination

Tags: react-admin

Is there a way to disable pagination as a whole? I want all my records to show up in one long list and not broken up into pages. I am using ListGuesser right now, and i have tried with both List and ListGuesser but i am unable disable pagination. Actually react-admin expects X-Total-Count from the server side and i don't want to introduce pagination, but i am bound to pass this in header to make it work. So is there any way to disable pagination?

```
<Resource name="posts" list={ListGuesser} edit={EditGuesser}/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a Simple Way to Disable Pagination. Set pagination={false} in List.
This works for me. And if you want to show more then 25 records on a page set perPage={100} or any no of value.
I don't know how long list react-admin support but it should work for like 500-1000 records.

Comment: Even pagination is set to false like you said, even then it expects x-Total-Count field in header. I don't want to pass this in header. Don't want to do this change in the backend to accomodate front-end. 
The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer Data Provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?

Comment: I have changed the pagination logic on my backend to make it work with react admin. Thanks

Comment: React Admin is bound to get X-Total-Count in the header. On that basis, it displays the list. And the list can be modified manually whether to display in pagination or on a single page. Without content range you can not use React Admin List to display records.

Comment: React-Admin is not bound to get this header. Some dataProviders are. To avoid this, you can write your own dataProvider